# How to add type bindings to graphql resolver mappings

Tags: typescript, graphql

Is there a standard way of adding type bindings to a graphql resolver mapping?

**sampleResolver.ts:**

```
export default {
  sampleResolver: (parent, args, context, info) => {
    ...
    return ...
  }
};
```

e.g.

```
sampleResolver<...>: (parent, args, context, info) => ...

or

sampleResolver: (parent, args, context, info): ... => ...

or

sampleResolver: (parent: ..., args: ..., context:..., info:...) => ...
```

[image]

Comment: (As in Apollo's / `graphql-tools`'s [resolver map](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data/)?)

Comment: Are you using Express along with Apollo GrapHQL?

Comment: @KingDarBoja, yes I am using `apollo-server-express`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `apollo-server-express` has implemented type definitions for resolvers as seen [on this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/404). However, you could try [graphql-code-generator](https://medium.com/the-guild/graphql-code-generator-v0-11-15bb9b02899e) to automatically generate type definitions for you schemas, resolvers and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that, see [more](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html). In your case i think this would be suitable:

**sampleResolver.ts**:

```
// Interface checking for return
export interface SampleResolver {
  [name: string]: any
}

// Then assign Interface at return
export default {
  sampleResolver: (parent, args, context, info) => {
    ...
    return <SampleResolver>...
  }
};
```

**Note**: The `export` is used for type checking in other files.

**otherFiles.ts**

```
import { SampleResolver } from 'sampleResolver';


var response: SampleResolver;
```